# @JsonIgnore just for some specific endpoints

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-data-jpa, annotations

I have been struggling to solve this issue on my project: Is possible to use the annotation `@JsonIgnore` only when endpoint has an specific value?

For example, i want to use the annotation when `endpoint.equals("xxxxxxxxx")`, but not use when `endpoint.equals("yyyyyy").`

There are 3 classes with these relationship annotations:

**Client**

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownerOfTheProduct")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Product> ownProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Category**

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Product> products;
```

**Product**

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Category category;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "CLIENT_PRODUCT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"))
    private Client ownerOfTheProduct;
```

The point is:

If i dont put the `@JsonIgnore`, i get a StackOverflow error, the json gets into looping and wont stop.

```
       "id": 1,
    "name": "Product name",
    "price": 20.0,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cleaning",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Product name",
                "price": 20.0,
                "category": {
                              ...
```

When i mapped in a different way, and put the `@JsonIgnore` into the both classes: **Client** and **Product**, it works, the loopings were not more hapenning. However, when i have to use other endpoint, which  the fields `products` and `ownerOfTheProduct` need to show up through api, it doesnt work cuz the `@JsonIgnore` is annotated.

**LOOPING SOLVED**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product name",
    "price": 20.0,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cleaning"
    },
    "ownOfTheProduct": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Edited",
        "cpf": "Edited",
        "email": "test",
        "password": "test"
    }
}
```

**OTHER ENDPOINTS ARE NOT WORKING**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Edited",
    "cpf": "Edited",
    "email": "test",
    "password": "test"
}
```

> I'd like the field that i have mapped with `@JsonIgnore` (ownProducts) shows up in this request exactly this way:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Edited",
    "cpf": "Edited",
    "email": "test",
    "password": "test"
    "ownProducts" [
           {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product name",
    "price": 20.0,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cleaning"
    },
                ]
}
```

---

Is there a way to change this? Summing up, i just want to use `@JsonIgnore` with especific especific endpoints, not every single endpoint on my API.

I hope yall got my question, anyway here is the link of the repository on github: https://github.com/reness0/spring-restapi-ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

While this is not possible to achieve using the annotation based approach (annotations make it static), you can achieve the same using any data mapper library. Create a filter based on the attribute from API. Orika library can be used: https://www.baeldung.com/orika-mapping

Answer (score 0):

You cant use only `@JsonIgnore` but you can use `@JsonView` and `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotations from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`

How it works:

1. You need define class with interfaces. For example:

   ```
   public class SomeView {

       public interface  id {}

       public interface CoreData extends id {}

       public interface FullData extends CoreData {}

   }
   ```
2. Mark entity fields with `@JsonView(<some interface.class>)`

   ```
   public class User {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       @JsonView(SomeView.id.class)
       private Long id;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @JsonView(SomeView.CoreData.class)
       private String username;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @JsonView(SomeView.FullData.class)
       private String email;
   }
   ```
3. Annotate endpoint with `@JsonView(<some interface.class>)`

   ```
    @GetMapping()
    @JsonView(SomeView.FullData.class)
    public User getUser() {
        return <get user entity somwhere>
    }
   ```

In case `@JsonView(SomeView.id.class)` you will get this JSON:

```
    {
        id: <some id>
    }
```

In case `@JsonView(SomeView.CoreData.class)`:

```
    {
        id: <some id>,
        username: <some username>
    }
```

In case `@JsonView(SomeView.FullData.class)`:

```
    {
        id: <some id>,
        username: <some username>,
        email: <some email>
    }
```

`@JsonView` also works with embeded objects and you can annotate one field with multiply views classes - `@JsonView({SomeView.FullData.class, SomeOtherView.OtherData.class})`

About Cycleing JSON. Annotate your entity class with

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    property = "id",
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class
)
```

Every time when JSON serialization go in circles object data will be replaced with object id or orher field of entity for your choose.

Or as alternative you can just use DTO classes